# How to extract the field from JSON object with QueryRecord

Tags: sql, json, apache-nifi, apache-calcite

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. I need to create a new JSON flowfile using QueryRecord by taking an array (field **ref**) from input JSON field **refs** and **skip** the object field as shown in example below:

### Input JSON flowfile

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "desc": "full1",
    "refs": {
        "ref": [
            {
                "source": "source1",
                "url": "url1"
            },
            {
                "source": "source2",
                "url": "url2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### QueryRecord configuration

JSONTreeReader setup as *Infer Schema* and JSONRecordSetWriter

```sql
select name, description, (array[rpath(refs, '//ref[*]')]) as sources from flowfile
```

### Output JSON (need)

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "desc": "full1",
    "references": [
         {
             "source": "source1",
             "url": "url1"
         },
         {
             "source": "source2",
             "url": "url2"
         }
    ]
}
```

But got error:
`QueryRecord Failed to write MapRecord[{references=[Ljava.lang.Object;@27fd935f, description=full1, name=name1}] with schema ["name" : "STRING", "description" : "STRING", "references" : "ARRAY[STRING]"] as a JSON Object due to java.lang.ClassCastException: null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!: use **JoltTransformJSON** to transform JSON by Jolt specification. [About this](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) specification.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach, in your case it shoud work:

1) Read your JSON field fully (I imitated it with GenerateFlowFile processor with your example)

2) Add EvaluateJsonPath processor which will put 2 header fileds (name, desc) into the attributes:
[image]

3) Add SplitJson processor which will split your JSON byt refs/ref/ groups (split by "$.refs.ref"):
[image]

4) Add ReplaceText processor which will add you header fields (name, desc) to the split lines (replace "[{]" value with "{"name":"${json.name}","desc":"${json.desc}","):
[image]

5) It`s done:

[image]

Full process in my demo case:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Of course, this doesn't solve the problem within a single QueryRecord element with an sql query, but it leads to the search for other solutions.